How to save hibernate FetchType.Lazy feature with Clean Architecture?
According to the clean architecture:

Your Entity objects should be plain old objects that have no dependencies on frameworks or databases or other complications.

As we see in Uncle Bob's diagram, the gateway (Repository) interface is coupled to Domain Entities.

At this point, I faced the problem because JpaRepositoty<T, ID> works only with classes with @Entity annotation, which is more about RDBMS than core business logic.
I found few solutions to make it more "clean":

Create Repository Interface in domain and in persistence layer create RepositoryImpl that will implement domain interface and will use EntityManager with POJO:

@Repository
public class DemoRepositoryImpl implements DemoRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Object[]> findAll() {
        Query q = (Query) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT\n" +
                "        demo.demo_id as demo_id,\n" +
                "        demo.value as demo_value\n" +
                "        FROM Demo\n");
        List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
}


Create interface in domain and couple implementtion with JpaRepositoty:

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DemoRepositoryImpl implements DemoRepository {

    private final JpaDemoRepository jpaDemoRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Demo> findAll() {
        return jpaDemoRepository.findAll().stream()
                                           .map(entity -> new Customer(entity.getId(), entity.getName()))
                                           .toList();
    }


Creating some dummy entity:

@Entity
@Data
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

public interface EmployeeDao extends JpaRepository<BaseEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select name from employee where employee_number = ?", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Employee> get(String employeeNumber);
}

public interface Employee{
    String getName();
}

However, they are ugly and deprived of certain JPA features, especially FetchType.Lazy.
I do not want to reduce the efficiency of the code with abstract "purity," but using Hibernate, my application is strongly tied to Hibernate and relational databases. Using Hibernate inside a Domain greatly complicates the transition to another JPA implementation, JOOQ, or even NoSQL and totally destroy clean architecture rules.
Is it worth being independent of Hibernate and relational Databases in large projects? Are there any solutions not to build an application around the Database, but also to be able to use most of JPA privileges?

Using Hibernate inside a Domain greatly complicates the transition to another JPA implementation, JOOQ, or even NoSQL and totally destroy clean architecture rules. - you are basically asking a customer to pay for work it does not need

@AndreyB.Panfilov So technically, any transition from Hibernate to something else shouldn't bother me at all. Do I understand you correctly? What a purpose of Clean Architecture, then?

Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Seems to be a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ rather than [so].

@AndyFlight Clean Architecture is a book and, no doubts, it's primary purpose is to earn money on sales, at the current moment it describes kind of imaginary world (no hackers, developers never do mistakes, systems have unlimited resources, customers do not change requirements, etc) - we are free to accept one ideas and refuse others.
